# How can I put a progress dialog while firebase is loading?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

How can I handle a Firebase thread, as an example, I want to populate a view holder with a recyclerview, I tried calling a dummy method like:

```
 private void load() {

     adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, ViewHolder>(
            ModelClass.class,
            R.layout.desgin_row_gridview,
            ViewHolder.class,
            mRef
```

While  `populateViewholder` method gets loaded
something like this:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, ModelClass 
model, int position) {
           viewHolder.mTitleView.setText(model.getTitle());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.mImageIv);
```

I want to show a progress dialog, check if its loaded and the viewholder is populated and then dismiss the progress dialog.

any insights?

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how it can be done using `onDataChange()` method.

Answer (score 3):

> mProgressDialog.show();

before adapter initialization and then

try overriding `onDataChanged()` in your adapter:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(...) {

  @Override
  protected void onDataChanged() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }

};
```